# Hang at bios boot screen when igpu multi-monitor activated with new hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, multiple-monitors, hardware-failure

Recently my 500gb hard drive fail so i changed it with a 160gb hard drive because that's the only one I have on hand. I installed Windows 7 on it and it works fine with igpu multi-monitor activated on bios. The next day I bought a 500gb hdd to add to my setup and add it as my secondary drive.
When I tried to boot my PC it stuck at bios splash screen(the one that show press f2 to enter bios). After several attempt to fix it I found out that the issue happen because igpu multi-monitor is enabled in bios. I really need the multi-monitor for my work so I tried to fix it, this is what I get:

- 160gb drive with multi-monitor enabled= boot normally
- 160gb drive with multi-monitor disabled= boot normally
- 500gb drive with multi-monitor enabled= hang at bios splash screen
- 500gb drive with multi-monitor disabled= boot normally
- 160gb + 500gb drive with multi-monitor enabled= hang at bios splash screen
- 160gb + 500gb drive with multi-monitor disabled= boot normally

At first I thought it was power issue, the psu doesn't have enough power to power my system so i tried to boot it with only the 500gb drive but it seems to not be the case because it still hang at splash screen with multi-monitor enabled, I also tried to disconnect the DVD drive with the same result. It's weird because the previously failure drive is also 500gb but have no issue with multi-monitor. Is it possible if the 500gb drive is no good? But if that so isn't it usually will let me access the BIOS even with drive failure?

I don't really need dual drive setup, i only hope that the 500gb drive to work with multi-monitor enabled, so I don't really mind if the 160gb drive is removed. Any answer on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After getting a replacement drive because I thought the new drive is busted but again greeted with the same error, I tried updating the bios and it fixed it.